# PHP Spintax : How to exclude CSS code with REGEX

Tags: php, regex, spintax

I have to do a regex to spin the content.
I already have a REGEX that works very well on nested spin :

```
{([^{}]+?)}
```

Unfortunately in my source code, I also have CSS code that matches because of the braces.

Like this (there can be several style tags):

```html
<style>
#test a{
color:red;
font-size:13px;
font-family:Arial;
}
</style>
```

Therefore I need to exclude all these styles tag and spin content with a single REGEX.

Any ideas?
In advance thank you

Comment: What is spintax for those that don't know?  Could you add some examples.  Oh and can you include your regex code with inputs, your output and desired outputs.

Comment: Use DOMDocument to only select content that isn't in style tags (or in script tags if any).

Comment: Note also that using a non-greedy quantifier in your pattern is useless (and slower) since curly brackets are excluded from your character class.

Comment: Spintax is Spinning content . DomDocument raises quite a lot of errors if there is any problem in the HTML

Comment: @Pisk Please show a [mcve].  We may be able to help you with the errors that DomDocument is raising.  Until this question is edited, it is unfortunately incomplete and may be closed as Unclear.